# using functions with the same name doing different stuff

Tags: function-construction, programming

I am trying to use functions with the same name, but which do different stuff.
Let me show an example.

```
predef[x_] := x^3 - x^2 + 2x -1;
g[x_,y_] := x^2 + 2 x y - y +3;      
func[] := Print[predef[4]];
func[f_[x_,y_]] := Print[f[2, 3]];
func[list_] := Print[list[[4]]];
```

Now the first func call returns returns 55; fine.
The  last call works fine too, but the second call using the g 
function as a parameter returns 2x y, but I have expected it to return 16.
What’s going on here?

Comment: You need to add `SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst]` to avoid evaluation of `g[x, y]` in the function call.

Answer (score 2):

The situation becomes more clear if you trace the evaluation of `func[g[x, y]]`:

```
ClearAll[func]
func[] := Print[predef[4]]
func[f_[x_, y_]] := Print[f[2, 3]]
func[list_] := Print[list[[4]]]

Trace@func[g[x, y]]

(* Out: {
 {HoldForm[g[x, y]], HoldForm[x^2 + 2*x*y - y + 3], HoldForm[3 + x^2 - y + 2*x*y]}, 
  HoldForm[func[3 + x^2 - y + 2*x*y]], 
  HoldForm[Print[(3 + x^2 - y + 2*x*y)[[4]]]], 
  {HoldForm[(3 + x^2 - y + 2*x*y)[[4]]], HoldForm[2*x*y]}, HoldForm[Print[2*x*y]], 
  .... }
*)
```

You see here that the first thing that happens during evaluation is that `g[x, y]` is evaluated to its value, i.e. `x^2 + 2*x*y - y + 3`.

The definition of `func` that applies then is the last one now, i.e. `func[list_] := Print[list[[4]]]` because that's the only one that applies to the polynomial passed to `func`, which is an expression with head `Plus`, which to Mathematica matches the `list_` pattern.

The evaluation then continues to `HoldForm[Print[(3 + x^2 - y + 2*x*y)[[4]]]]`, which prints the fourth part of the polynomial expression, which happens to be `2 x y`.

---

To avoid this you need to prevent premature evaluation of your function's arguments. This is what the `Hold` attributes do. In this case, you could use `HoldFirst` to hold the first argument unevaluated:

```
ClearAll[func]
func[] := Print[predef[4]]
func[f_[x_, y_]] := Print[f[2, 3]]
func[list_] := Print[list[[4]]]
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst]

func[g[x, y]]
(* out: 16 *)
```

You can see now the difference by tracing the evaluation:

```
Trace@func[g[x, y]]

(* Out: 
{func[g[x, y]],
 Print[g[2, 3]], 
 {g[2, 3], 
   2^2 + 2 2 3 - 3 + 3, 
   {2^2, 4}, {2 2 3, 12}, {-3, -3}, 4 + 12 - 3 + 3, 16}, 
 Print[16], ...}
*)
```

---

Additionally, I would also suggest that you restrict the last definition of your function to match only inputs that are *explicitly* lists:

```
ClearAll[func]
func[] := Print[predef[4]]
func[f_[x_, y_]] := Print[f[2, 3]]
func[list_List] := Print[list[[4]]] (*notice the _List restriction *)
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst]
```